# Why are my Datastore Write Ops so high?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I busted through my daily free quota on a new project this weekend. For reference, that's .05 million writes, or 50,000 if my math is right.

Below is the only code in my project that is making any Datastore write operations.

```
    old = Streams.query().fetch(keys_only=True)
    ndb.delete_multi(old)
    try:
        r = urlfetch.fetch(url=streams_url,
                           method=urlfetch.GET)
        streams = json.loads(r.content)
        for stream in streams['streams']:
            stream = Streams(channel_id=stream['_id'],
                             display_name=stream['channel']['display_name'],
                             name=stream['channel']['name'],
                             game=stream['channel']['game'],
                             status=stream['channel']['status'],
                             delay_timer=stream['channel']['delay'],
                             channel_url=stream['channel']['url'],
                             viewers=stream['viewers'],
                             logo=stream['channel']['logo'],
                             background=stream['channel']['background'],
                             video_banner=stream['channel']['video_banner'],
                             preview_medium=stream['preview']['medium'],
                             preview_large=stream['preview']['large'],
                             videos_url=stream['channel']['_links']['videos'],
                             chat_url=stream['channel']['_links']['chat'])
            stream.put()
        self.response.out.write("Done")
    except urlfetch.Error, e:
        self.response.out.write(e)
```

This is what I know:

- There will never be more than 25 "stream" in "streams." It's
  guaranteed to call .put() exactly 25 times.
- I delete everything from the table at the start of this call because everything needs to be refreshed every time it runs.
- Right now, this code is on a cron running every 60 seconds. It will never run more often than once a minute.
- I have verified all of this by enabling Appstats and I can see the datastore_v3.Put count go up by 25 every minute, as intended.

I have to be doing something wrong here, because 25 a minute is 1,500 writes an hour, not the ~50,000 that I'm seeing now.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are mixing two different things here: write API calls (what your code calls) and low-level datastore write operations. See the billing docs for relations: [Pricing of Costs for Datastore Calls](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/billing#Billable_Resource_Unit_Costs) (second section).

This is the relevant part:

`New Entity Put (per entity, regardless of entity size) = 2 writes + 2 writes per indexed property value + 1 write per composite index value`

In your case `Streams` has 15 indexed properties resulting in: 2 + 15 * 2 = 32 write OPs per write API call.

Total per hour: 60 (requests/hour) * 25 (puts/request) * 32 (operations/put) = **48,000** datastore write operations per hour

Comment: Peter, I just noticed your answer now. Apologies for being late but thanks so much for helping me understand why this was happening. 48,000 an hour seems just about what I was finding. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

It seems as though I've finally figured out what was going on, so I wanted to update here.
I found this older answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17079348/1452497.

I've missed somewhere along the line where the properties being indexed were somehow multiplying the writes by factors of at least 10, I did not expect that. I didn't need everything indexed and after turning off the index in my model, I've noticed the write ops drop DRAMATICALLY. Down to about where I expect them.

Thanks guys!

Comment: See my answer on why indexes "multiply" datastore write operations.

Answer (score 1):

It is 1500*24=36,000 writes/day, which is very near to the daily quota.

Comment: Aye, 36,000 a day is what I expected. I'm seeing about 50,000 an HOUR.